# How to customize calender to show only one row

Tags: android

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html?showComment=1374298656772#c7739428050175524218). How do I show only the current week in the calendar, not all 31 days in a month?

This example shows 5 rows, however I only want it to show one row which is the current week row. Suppose today's date is 15 and a Thursday, then it should show something like this:

```
Sun  Mon  TU  WED  THU     FRI  SAT
11   12   13  14   **15**  16   17
```

No other week of dates will be shown. In this other date, it's the 3rd and a Friday:

```
Sun  Mon  TU  WED  THU  FRI  SAT
29   30   31  1    2    3    4
```

Class

```
      public class MyCalendarActivity extends Activity implements    
    OnClickListener {
    private static final String tag = "MyCalendarActivity";

    private TextView currentMonth;
  private Button selectedDayMonthYearButton;
   private ImageView prevMonth;
  private ImageView nextMonth;
   private GridView calendarView;
    private GridCellAdapter adapter;
   private Calendar _calendar;
   @SuppressLint("NewApi")
  private int month, year;
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
   private final DateFormat dateFormatter = new DateFormat();
    private static final String dateTemplate = "MMMM yyyy";

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.my_calendar_view);

   _calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
   month = _calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
   year = _calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    Log.d(tag, "Calendar Instance:= " + "Month: " + month + " " + "Year: "
    + year);

   selectedDayMonthYearButton = (Button) this
     .findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
    selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: ");

     prevMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.prevMonth);
   prevMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

    currentMonth = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.currentMonth);
    currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
   _calendar.getTime()));

    nextMonth = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.nextMonth);
     nextMonth.setOnClickListener(this);

   calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);

    // Initialised
   adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
    R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

  /**
  * 
  * @param month
   * @param year
   */
   private void setGridCellAdapterToDate(int month, int year) {
   adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
   R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
  _calendar.set(year, month - 1, _calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  currentMonth.setText(DateFormat.format(dateTemplate,
  _calendar.getTime()));
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
  if (v == prevMonth) {
 if (month <= 1) {
 month = 12;
 year--;
} else {
 month--;
}
 Log.d(tag, "Setting Prev Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
 + month + " Year: " + year);
setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
}
if (v == nextMonth) {
if (month > 11) {
month = 1;
year++;
} else {
month++;
}
Log.d(tag, "Setting Next Month in GridCellAdapter: " + "Month: "
 + month + " Year: " + year);
setGridCellAdapterToDate(month, year);
}

}

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
 Log.d(tag, "Destroying View ...");
  super.onDestroy();
 }

// Inner Class
 public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {
 private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
  private final Context _context;

   private final List<String> list;
  private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
 private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
  "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
 private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
 "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
 "October", "November", "December" };
  private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
   31, 30, 31 };
  private int daysInMonth;
  private int currentDayOfMonth;
  private int currentWeekDay;
  private Button gridcell;
  private TextView num_events_per_day;
  private final HashMap<String, Integer> eventsPerMonthMap;
  private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
   "dd-MMM-yyyy");

  // Days in Current Month
  public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
  int month, int year) {
  super();
 this._context = context;
 this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
 + "Year: " + year);
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
 setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
 Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
   Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
  Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

   // Print Month
  printMonth(month, year);

   // Find Number of Events
  eventsPerMonthMap = findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(year, month);
  }

 private String getMonthAsString(int i) {
  return months[i];
 }

 private String getWeekDayAsString(int i) {
 return weekdays[i];
  }

  private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
 return daysOfMonth[i];
}

 public String getItem(int position) {
  return list.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public int getCount() {
  return list.size();
 }

 /**
* Prints Month
* 
* @param mm
* @param yy
   */
 private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
int trailingSpaces = 0;
int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
 int prevMonth = 0;
int prevYear = 0;
int nextMonth = 0;
int nextYear = 0;

 int currentMonth = mm - 1;
 String currentMonthName = getMonthAsString(currentMonth);
  daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

 Log.d(tag, "Current Month: " + " " + currentMonthName + " having "
 + daysInMonth + " days.");

 GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);
 Log.d(tag, "Gregorian Calendar:= " + cal.getTime().toString());

 if (currentMonth == 11) {
  prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
  daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  nextMonth = 0;
  prevYear = yy;
  nextYear = yy + 1;
  Log.d(tag, "*->PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
  } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
 prevMonth = 11;
 prevYear = yy - 1;
 nextYear = yy;
 daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
  nextMonth = 1;
 Log.d(tag, "**--> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
 } else {
 prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
 nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
 nextYear = yy;
 prevYear = yy;
 daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
 Log.d(tag, "***---> PrevYear: " + prevYear + " PrevMonth:"
  + prevMonth + " NextMonth: " + nextMonth
  + " NextYear: " + nextYear);
 }

      int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
      trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;

  Log.d(tag, "Week Day:" + currentWeekDay + " is "
 + getWeekDayAsString(currentWeekDay));
 Log.d(tag, "No. Trailing space to Add: " + trailingSpaces);
 Log.d(tag, "No. of Days in Previous Month: " + daysInPrevMonth);

 if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)))
 if (mm == 2)
 ++daysInMonth;
 else if (mm == 3)
 ++daysInPrevMonth;

 // Trailing Month days
 for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {
 Log.d(tag,
  "PREV MONTH:= "
    + prevMonth
    + " => "
    + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
    + " "
    + String.valueOf((daysInPrevMonth
      - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
      + i));
 list.add(String
  .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
    + i)
  + "-GREY"
  + "-"
  + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
  + "-"
  + prevYear);
  }

   // Current Month Days
  for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
  Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
  + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
  if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
   + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
  } else {
  list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
    + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
  }
  }

 // Leading Month days
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {
 Log.d(tag, "NEXT MONTH:= " + getMonthAsString(nextMonth));
 list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
  + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
 }
 }

 /**
* NOTE: YOU NEED TO IMPLEMENT THIS PART Given the YEAR, MONTH, retrieve
 * ALL entries from a SQLite database for that month. Iterate over the
* List of All entries, and get the dateCreated, which is converted into
* day.
* 
* @param year
* @param month
* @return
*/
 private HashMap<String, Integer> findNumberOfEventsPerMonth(int year,
 int month) {
 HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

 return map;
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
 return position;
}

 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
 View row = convertView;
 if (row == null) {
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
   .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_gridcell, parent, false);
 }

 // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
 gridcell = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
 gridcell.setOnClickListener(this);

// ACCOUNT FOR SPACING

 Log.d(tag, "Current Day: " + getCurrentDayOfMonth());
 String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
 String theday = day_color[0];
 String themonth = day_color[2];
  String theyear = day_color[3];
 if ((!eventsPerMonthMap.isEmpty()) && (eventsPerMonthMap != null)) {
 if (eventsPerMonthMap.containsKey(theday)) {
 num_events_per_day = (TextView) row
   .findViewById(R.id.num_events_per_day);
 Integer numEvents = (Integer) eventsPerMonthMap.get(theday);
 num_events_per_day.setText(numEvents.toString());
 }
 }

 // Set the Day GridCell
 gridcell.setText(theday);
 gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);
 Log.d(tag, "Setting GridCell " + theday + "-" + themonth + "-"
  + theyear);

 if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
  gridcell.setTextColor(getResources()
   .getColor(R.color.lightgray));
 }
 if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
 gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
  R.color.lightgray02));
}
if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orrange));
}
return row;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String date_month_year = (String) view.getTag();
selectedDayMonthYearButton.setText("Selected: " + date_month_year);
Log.e("Selected date", date_month_year);
try {
 Date parsedDate = dateFormatter.parse(date_month_year);
 Log.d(tag, "Parsed Date: " + parsedDate.toString());

 } catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }

public int getCurrentDayOfMonth() {
  return currentDayOfMonth;
}

 private void setCurrentDayOfMonth(int currentDayOfMonth) {
 this.currentDayOfMonth = currentDayOfMonth;
 }

public void setCurrentWeekDay(int currentWeekDay) {
this.currentWeekDay = currentWeekDay;
 }

 public int getCurrentWeekDay() {
 return currentWeekDay;
}
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you say what the problem is, and where its at?

Comment: i want to customize this sample example code to show only current wek of days    http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/10/custom-calendar-in-android.html?showComment=1374298656772#c7739428050175524218  now all 31 days show on display

Comment: Please be specific about the problem. Major changes need to be made to get what you are looking for. If you are stuck somewhere at the moment, provide some details. For a start, the list that your adapter uses should contains 7 items.

Comment: i want to show calender like this way  http://imgur.com/2lwWclW    single row and highlight current date in  calender

Comment: i did i change this line  // Current Month Days
  for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

with this 
// Current Month Days
   for (int i = 1; i <= currentWeekDay; i++) {
now is show only single row of week but is 1 to 7 only not today date will show

Comment: help me how i show only current week of day si n calender

Comment: did you solve this problem ?